# Ember router resume on reload

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

I have an ember.js router based application with an interesting quirk. Since the router documentation is rather sparse, I'm not sure if this is a *feature* or a *bug* or an un-intended consequence of some of my code elsewhere.

When I reload the page containing the app in my browser, the App jumps to the route of where I last was. I have the routes serialized as a hash. So an example would be I'm on `app.html#/users/1/details` and I delete the hash and add a random query variable `app.html?reload=randomnumber` and load the page. As soon as ember loads, it is adding the `#/users/1/details` back to that address.

Is this a feature/consequence of ember, or is it some junk that I wrote. I haven't found anything that I wrote that could be causing this so far.

If it is an ember feature, is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

What are you calling "***reload***", exactly?

Ember cannot keep any state in your browser when route is serialized using a hash. It has nothing to see with Ember: when reloading the page, the whole state is lost, and reset according to requested url returned content initializations.

Nevertheless, when a hash is present, it is used by Ember to reset the router's state.

So what I would suspect is you are still reloading the URL `.../app.html#/users/1/details`.

Did you take a look at your Network history, in the developer tools *(or equivalent)*?

The first item should be a GET request, and it will indicate the effective requested URL and the hash if any.

Comment: Thanks I wasn't sure if Ember used any of the newer browsers' persistance features to save its state or some nonsense like that. The hash string isn't getting sent in the get request, but I think the Chrome browser is guilty of restoring it on page load, though I'll need to test a little more to comfirm. It must be assuming that I want to go to the anchor I was previously at. FYI my refresh method is something like `window.location = window.location.pathname + '?reload' + App.generateRandVal()`.